# Change background-color with javascript, with same button no jquery or other

Tags: javascript, background-color

function changeColor() {
var bgcolor = document.getElementById("paper");

```
              if (bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "white") {
                bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "red";
              } else if (bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "red")                 {   
                bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "white";
              }
            }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your html and css as well.

Comment: How to I change the colors, to like slateGrey and white without the rgb colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious mistake in your code.

In the if conditionals you are doing an assignement with = instead of checking for equality with ===

Correct would be like this:

```
function changeColor() { 
var bgcolor = document.getElementById("paper");
if (bgcolor.style.backgroundColor === "white") {
   bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else if (bgcolor.style.backgroundColor === "red"){   
   bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
  }
```

And in reponse to your comment. What you are checking for in your javascript is inline styles. Since you don't have any inline styles to begin with...and only styles in your css that condition of bgColor.style.backgroundColor === 'white' will never be true so your inline style will never be added. Therefore the function will never fire.

What you can do to make it work is to add at the beginning inline style for background color white for the paper div or check for computedStyles instead like this:

```js
function changeColor() { 
var bgcolor = document.getElementById("paper");
if (getComputedStyle(bgcolor).backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 255)") {
   bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "red";
} else if (getComputedStyle(bgcolor).backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){   
   bgcolor.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#1e1e1e;
    padding:2em;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    height:100vh;
}

.paper {
    width:50em;
    background-color:white;
    padding:1em;
    border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px #888888;
}

h1 {
    padding:.5em;
    color:#242424;
}

p {
    padding:1em;
    color:#393939;
}



button {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #AAAAAA;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #AAAAAA), color-stop(1, #AAAAAA));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #AAAAAA 5%, #AAAAAA 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#AAAAAA', endColorstr='#AAAAAA',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#77b55a;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #4b8f29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
button:hover, button.selected {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #FF851B), color-stop(1, #FF851B));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF851B 5%, #FF851B 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF851B', endColorstr='#FF851B',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#FF851B;
}
button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="paper" id="paper">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas alias accusamus id impedit architecto iure qui? Vel doloremque omnis nesciunt at atque expedita, molestias ratione quidem consequuntur voluptatum velit perspiciatis amet ut neque adipisci iure incidunt iusto. Libero laudantium possimus architecto commodi totam minus doloremque.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis, pariatur odit laboriosam consequatur ex deserunt doloremque quae temporibus necessitatibus nam veritatis aspernatur ad eius possimus, quas distinctio alias nostrum rerum illo eos deleniti incidunt sequi dolores. Cumque, iusto earum.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot get it to work in my pen: https://codepen.io/martin-wichmand/pen/BapNEBb

Comment: Wow, thanks... I am a total newbie to Javascript, and you just learned me a valuable lesson...